# Trying to understand zip

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am attempting to understand how to use zip in Haskell. I've been learning Haskell recently and am trying to create a list of tuples from two separate lists

I have the following:

```
createList :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [(Char,Char)]    
createList xs ys = zip(xs,ys)
```

I understand zip is supposed to create a list of tuples given two lists, but I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’
              with actual type ‘([Char], [Char])’
```

Can anyone explain to me where I am stumbling?

Answer (score 5):

Haskell function calls don't use brackets or commas.

You can write the `createList` function as:

```
createList xs ys = zip xs ys
```

or simply

```
createList = zip
```

Thus, the `createList` function is redundant; it's just `zip`. The only potential use for the alias that I can think of is if you truly want to constrain the type as given.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the parenthesis around `zip` call, your code should work:

```hs
createList :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [(Char,Char)]

createList xs ys = zip xs ys
```

### Explanation:

Full error I am getting when I run `zip ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])` (notice the parens):

```
<interactive>:4:5:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’
                with actual type ‘([Integer], [Integer])’
    Relevant bindings include
      it :: [b] -> [(a, b)] (bound at <interactive>:4:1)
    In the first argument of ‘zip’, namely ‘([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])’
    In the expression: zip ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = zip ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Notice the part that says `In the first argument of ‘zip’, namely ‘([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])’`.  The parens are interpreted as [tuple constructor](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28%2C%29&scope=set%3Astackage).  `zip` function expects a list as its first argument but we are passing it a tuple.